# How to implement notification settings in Phonegap app

Tags: cordova, notifications, phonegap-build, phonegap

### My Question

I want to implement notification settings for my Phonegap app, something like this:[image: notification setting]
What is the best way to achieve it?

### My Research

In my research, I found information about the installation of different push notification plugins and recommendations to implement notification settings but no luck with this specific question I asked above.

### My Knowledge

I am new to Phonegap and even mobile development and building my first mobile app.

### My Assumption

I am assuming that I have to have a server where I would store these settings for each user and my code will look for these settings for each user before sending them notifications.

### My Environment

- Using Phonegap build cli-7.0.1
- For notification through FCM, using
  [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push)
- So far I don't have server to store any user data or to send notification from. I tested FCM notification though FCM web interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [firebase](https://firebase.google.com) for the required purpose. FCM for sending the notifications and **firebase cloud functions** for the server-side processing. You have to use FCM for android/ios and not web for phonegap-push-plugin.**FYI** firebase does offer a free plan and also the learning curve is not very steep.